# Trouble calling a .DLL function from a Console Application

Tags: c, dll, import

I really need your help because I'm having many problems integrating one .DLL function  into my Console Application.This .DLL consists on getting 2 chars(Char a and Char b)(Input) and adding them to one char.For example:
    Char A=H
    Char B=I
    Output=HI
    But here's the problem.When I compile the console application and when I run it,it says that the function hasn't been detected.And here's my question..Why the hell doesn't it find the function even though in the .def file I've listed the LIBRARY and the only exported function?Please help me.
    **THIS IS THE .DLL SOURCE**

```
        #include "stdafx.h"
    char concatenazione(char a,char b)
    {
    return a+b;
    }

**THIS IS THE .DEF FILE OF THE .DLL**

    LIBRARY Concatenazione
    EXPORTS
    concatenazione @1

**And this is the dllmain.cpp**


#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
**This is the Console Application partial source(For now it just includes the functions import part)**

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPWSTR); 

int main( void ) 
{ 
    HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    MYPROC ProcAdd; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\ConcatenazioneDiAyoub.dll")); 

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.

    if (hinstLib != NULL) 
    { 
        ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "concatenazione"); 

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.

        if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
        {
            fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
            (ProcAdd) (L"Message sent to the DLL function\n"); 
        }
        // Free the DLL module.

        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
    } 

    // If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
    if (! fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
        printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

    return 0;

}
**The Console Applications runs fine but the output is "Message printed from executable".This means that the function hasn't been detected.**
```

Comment: I would advise you [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8(v=vs.80).aspx), then put better error handling and reporting in your code to determine whether it is a failure to load the DLL or a failure to find the proc that is occurring.

Comment: You might like to add the path to the DLL to the `PATH`enviroment variable prior to running to app which tries to make use of the DLL.

Comment: Now it doesn't give me that message

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I looked at what you have above and wondered where in your code you import the dll. I'm kind of new at this myself, so I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc301501.aspx) on how to do it.

If I understand correctly, in your console application you need to have a line like (assuming the name of your dll is "your.dll":

```
[DllImport("your.Dll")]
```

by the way, welcome to Stack Overflow, I noticed it is your first day!  CHEERS!

Comment: I already use the LoadLibrary command to load the .DLL...btw..Thanks for the welcome :)

Comment: Note: this isn't a C# console application; it is C.

Comment: oops, my bad. I guess I should learn to read. Hmm. Should I toss this answer, or leave it because it contains a welcome?

Comment: yeah that's what I wanted to say...I'm using C++ actually